# Amazon EC2: what is key and secret fields for PHP SDK config.inc.php?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, ec2-api-tools

I know amazon ec2 public key, key-pair name and SSH authorized_keys in .ssh directory.
During PHP SDK configuration, i have fill config.inc.php with key and secret field.

I am unable to relate public key, key-pair name and SSH authorized_keys with key and secret fields.

Where will i get these values?

```
// Amazon Web Services Key. Found in the AWS Security Credentials. You can also pass
// this value as the first parameter to a service constructor.
'key' => 'development-key',

// Amazon Web Services Secret Key. Found in the AWS Security Credentials. You can also
// pass this value as the second parameter to a service constructor.
'secret' => 'development-secret',
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The api credentials are completely unrelated to ssh keys. Your api key info can be found on the security credentials page (follow the my account link from the amazon web console)

You can read about the various amazon credentials and their uses [here](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSecurityCredentials/1.0/AboutAWSCredentials.html)